# convert rows into columns in SQL Server is not working

Tags: sql-server

Need help to fix this problem.The Input , output table and query is given below. Below query is giving only one record as output.

Can anyone tell me what changes is required to get the both records.

Thanks in advance .

Sample input:

Input table name: ABC

```
 COL_NAME   COL_VALUE   FLAG 
 ---------------------------
 COL_1        100        N
 COL_2        RAM        N
 COL_3        KOL        N
 COL_1        345        N
 COL_2        SAM        N
 COL_3        DEL        N
 COL_1        348        Y
 COL_2        TAM        Y
 COL_3        MUM        Y
```

Expected output:

Output table name: XYZ

```
   COL_1   COL_2   COL_3   FLAG
   -----------------------------
   100     RAM     KOL      N
   345     SAM     DEL      N
```

Query:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM ABC WHERE FLAG='N')>0
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO XYZ
SELECT
   MAX(CASE WHEN COL_NAME='COL_1'THEN COL_VALUE END)COL_1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN COL_NAME='COL_2'THEN COL_VALUE END)COL_2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN COL_NAME='COL_3'THEN COL_VALUE END)COL_3,
   MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG='N'THEN FLAG END)FLAG,
   FROM ABC
END

Queries output:
   COL_1 ,COL_2, COL_3 FLAG
   100,  RAM,   KOL  ,N
```

2nd record is not populated.

Thanks,
Erico

Comment: Looks like you are using an aggregate in all of your output columns, this will only ever return one row. You should consider including some differentiating value where the `MAX` aggregations are relevant.

Comment: tries to put MAX in required place but it is not giving the required output

Answer (score 0):

Using MAX function makes the script to select only one value. Don't use it and you will have all records. Just use CASE WHEN...

Comment: Thanks Alex for responding but output is not as expected.   Output looks like inline `COL_1 ,COL_2, COL_3 FLAG
   100,  
       RAM,   
           KOL  
           ,N
   345,
       SAM,
           DEL
           ,N`,

Comment: its create 8 records in output